# Sol2 unable to iterate over vector

Tags: c++, lua

I'm attempting to give a list of integers to a Lua script, and iterate over them.

The error I'm getting is:

`test.lua:12: bad argument #1 to 'pairs' (table expected, got userdata)
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'pairs'
        test.lua:12: in main chunk`

The C++ code being used:

```
#include <sol.hpp>

struct Test {
    std::vector<int> a;
};

int main(void) {
    sol::state lua;

    lua.open_libraries(sol::lib::base);

    lua.new_usertype<Test>("test",
        "a", &Test::a);

    lua.script_file("test.lua", [](lua_State* L, sol::protected_function_result pfr) {
        sol::error err = pfr;
        std::cout << err.what() << std::endl;
        return pfr;
    });
}
```

The Lua script:

```
t = test.new()

for i in pairs(t.a) do
  print(i)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO I know this is an old question, but I came across this problem myself when first learning how to do this so I thought I'd add this answer for anyone coming across this now.

The problem isn't with your C++ code, it's with your Lua code. Lua uses colons ( : ) instead of full stops ( . ) for member calls, so it should look like this:

```
t = test:new()

for k,v in pairs(t.a) do
  print(v)
end
```

Emphasis on member calls, mind you. Properties are still accessed with full stops. If you have a user type CObject with the function ExFnc, you could call it on object ExampleObj either of the two following ways:

```
ExampleObj:ExFnc()
```

or

```
CObject.ExFnc(ExampleObj)
```

sol (at least the version I used, 3.0.2) provides a whole assortment of container mappings already included that just work right out of the box. You can find details for them here: [sol 3.0.2 containers documentation](https://sol2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/containers.html)

It lists automatic compatibility with the following types:

- std::vector
- std::deque
- std::list
- std::forward_list
- std::array
- std::set
- std::multi_set
- std::map
- std::multi_map
- std::unordered_set
- std::unordered_multiset
- std::unordered_map
- std::unordered_multimap

Keep in mind though that NAMESPACES in sol are tables, you have to use full stops for those.

Answer (score 0):

`pairs` is a Lua function that only takes a single variable of type `table` as input. t is of type `userdata`, hence the error.

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-pairs

You have two options here:

- implement a version of `pairs` that can handle your userdata type
- copy all elements into a table befor you feed that into `pairs`

Also ask yourself if it makes any sense to use pairs on a vector. A numeric for loop would feel much more natural. I'd even prefer `ipairs` over `pairs`